# Cannot perform an ORDERBY against my EF4 data

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

I have a query hitting EF4 using STEs and I'm having an issue with user-defined sorting. In debugging this, I have removed the dynamic sorting and am hard-coding it and I still have the issue. If I swap/uncomment the `var results = xxx` lines in `GetMyBusinesses()`, my results are not sorted any differently - they are always sorting it ascendingly.

FYI, `Name` is a `varchar(200)` field in SQL 2008 on my Business table.

```
private IQueryable<Business> GetMyBusinesses(MyDBContext CurrentContext)
{

    var myBusinesses = from a in CurrentContext.A
                       join f in CurrentContext.F
                           on a.FID equals f.id
                       join b in CurrentContext.Businesses
                           on f.BID equals b.id
                       where a.PersonID == 52
                       select b;

    var results = from r in myBusinesses
              orderby "Name" ascending
              select r;

    //var results = from r in results
    //          orderby "Name" descending
    //          select r;

    return results;
}

private PartialEntitiesList<Business> DoStuff()
{
    var myBusinesses = GetMyBusinesses();
    var myBusinessesCount = GetMyBusinesses().Count();

    Results = new PartialEntitiesList<Business>(myBusinesses.Skip((PageNumber - 1)*PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList())
                  {UnpartialTotalCount = myBusinessesCount};

    return Results;
}

public class PartialEntitiesList<T> : List<T>
{
    public PartialEntitiesList()
    {
    }

    public PartialEntitiesList(int capacity) : base(capacity)
    {
    }

    public PartialEntitiesList(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
    {
    }

    public int UnpartialTotalCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: STE? Self trackinhg entities?

Comment: @Craig: Sorry, that was a leftover artifact of my dynamic stuff that I'm using. I've fixed me code to remove that.

Comment: @Steven: Yes, STE = Self-Tracking Entities.

Comment: Evaluate the result in the debugger before it's returned. Is it correct? If so, something else is changing the sort elsewhere.

Comment: @Craig: What I'm doing is invalid syntax that throws no exceptions. :-/  See my answer below.

Comment: On a side note, I'm further investigating the ability to accomplish my larger picture goal with the following question. However, I'd still like to continue this discussion, Craig. :-)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759759/performing-dynamic-sorts-on-ef4-data

Comment: Well, I do what @tvanfosson does; use Dynamic LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently having the `OrderBy` clause as a string is invalid (I thought I had tested that before?!). If I change my Linq query to the following, then it works:

```
var results = from r in myBusinesses
          orderby r.Name ascending
          select r;
```

This doesn't solve my problem but it does answer this specific question. I'll be posting another question related to my problem.

Comment: It's not invalid; it's just not what you expect. `orderby "Name"` compiles to `.OrderBy("Name")` which expects ESQL. `"Name"` isn't valid, but `"it.Name"` is. So `orderby "it.Name"` might actually work.

Comment: @Craig: I have actually tried what would be the equivalent of `"it." + "Name"` long ago and had no luck with that. I assume the fact that I'd be adding the strings together wouldn't have affected the validity of it?

Comment: No, that would have no effect. The key insight here is that the language integrated query (`orderby`) and the method call (`.OrderBy`) compile to the same thing.